# Only first image appears from an array?

Tags: arrays, svg, processing

I found [this example](https://www.openprocessing.org/sketch/87384/) of exactly what I want to do except with .svg files. It appears to work as I have to click the right arrow 6 times to show the first image again. Is there a reason why the other svg images aren't showing?

Here is the code I adapted:

```
int maxImages = 6; // Total # of images
int imageIndex = 0; // Initial image to be displayed is the first
boolean isPlaying = false;

// Declaring an array of images.
PShape[] images = new PShape[maxImages];

void setup() {
  size(1080,1920);

  // Loading the images into the array
  // Don't forget to put the JPG files in the data folder!
  for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i ++ ) {
    images[i] = loadShape( "HairStyles" + i + ".svg" ); 

  }

  frameRate(5);
}

void draw() {

  background(100);
  shape(images[imageIndex],500,500); 
}

// Only happens when you release key
void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
    // Cycle
    if (imageIndex >= 5) {
      imageIndex = 0;
    }
    else {
      imageIndex += 1;
    }
  }
  else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
    // Cycle backwards
    if (imageIndex <= 0) {
      imageIndex = 5;
    }
    else {
      imageIndex -= 1;
    }
  }
}
```

It's pretty much the same as the example,  could my problem be something to do with the exported files?

Comment: I suspect the loop might break while loading the images. Try loading them like this to see if this could be the issue: `string imgName = "HairStyles" + i + ".svg";` `images[i] = loadShape(imgName);` and keep an eye on the console for an unexpected file name or a loading error (if the file doesn't load right the function will return a null and will write an error message to the console).

Comment: Can you double check the file names? Are your sure your loop is loading the correct files?

Comment: @KevinWorkman triple checked, that was my first though too. It seems to be looping through them but they're just not showing

Comment: @laancelot doesn't appear to have changed anything. I swapped the order of the images and still only one is showing, I will export them again and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: SOLVED: they weren't showing because they didn't have a fill colour, only a stroke. I disabled the styles and added a stroke.